# Date parsing problem with Jackson 1.8.5

Tags: java, json, date, jackson

Recently (in the last couple hours or so) I started getting this exception stack:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Numeric value (1316835995324) out of range of int
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@5b082d45; line: 1, column: 642]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1291)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:385)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonNumericParserBase.convertNumberToInt(JsonNumericParserBase.java:462)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonNumericParserBase.getIntValue(JsonNumericParserBase.java:257)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializer._parseInteger(StdDeserializer.java:237)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializer$IntegerDeserializer.deserialize(StdDeserializer.java:838)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializer$IntegerDeserializer.deserialize(StdDeserializer.java:825)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:252)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:494)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:350)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:120)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:97)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:26)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:252)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:499)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:494)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:350)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:252)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:499)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:494)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:350)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:120)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:97)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:26)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:252)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:499)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:494)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:350)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:252)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:499)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:494)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:350)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:120)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:97)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:26)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:252)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:499)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:494)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:350)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:477)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:253)
```

This is happening while deserializing a `java.util.Date`. The interesing part is that there are other similar `Date`s in the input stream before this one and they do not cause any problems. In addition, I did not change the fields of the object that is being serialized and deserialized.

Does anyone have any idea why Jackson is trying to deserialize this particular `Date` value into an `int` (and not into a `long`)?

Thanks in advance for any insight.

EDIT: I debugged this a little and it looks like this is the first `Date` that Jackson is trying to process, even though it still comes later in the stream. I also saw that Jackson is trying to force this number into an `int`, even though earlier in the processing it is detected properly as a `long`.

EDIT 2: I debugged this more and figured out the following: Serialization/deserialization works fine as long as I do not have a setter that takes an input parameter, like this:

```
public void setSomeValue(int param)
{
    // stuff
    this.date = <result_value>
}
```

The moment I introduce this setter, Jackson executes a different code path and ends up in the block where it tries to put a `long` (the `java.util.Date`) into an `int`.

EDIT 3: Changing the setter name to something unrelated to the field name works around the problem. I would still prefer to know if the original way is working as intended (if so, what is the idea behind it) or a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right -- type that is expected is determined by mutator with highest priority. So since your setter claims type is 'int', that's what Jackson treats it as. It actually must, since it will call that setter; so even if you happen to have a field with different type (or getter that returns Date), it won't help a lot since you can not pass Date as an 'int' to set method.

**INT_MIN** Minimum value for a variable of type int.   –**2147483648**

**INT_MAX** Maximum value for a variable of type int.   **2147483647**

Comment: The int was just a parameter that was passed to the setter to be used in calculating a `Date`. I did not take into account the fact that it would affect the processing of deserialization (I already have a `@JsonProperty` annotation on the field itself). If I get it right, the object is processed as a Bean (even though it may not be) hence the semantics on the getters and setters. It occurred to me now that using `@JsonIgnore` also helps. In any case, thank you for reading and providing an explanation.

Comment: No problem. What determines it really is precedences of pieces: methods do have higher precedence than fields, since this allows "overriding" of fields by adding accessors. Hope this helps going forward.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Since I learnt from your explanation that my "workaround" (in my "edit 3") is actually what I intended to do (i.e. not treat that function as some setter), I left it as it is and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

yep, check the setter, change int to long:

```
public void setSomeValue(long param)
{
     this.date = param;
}
```